# Parallelizing for loop

Tags: c, loops, openmp

I want to parallelize the following code with OpenMP:

```
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            sum += A[i][j]*x[j];
        }
        y[i]=sum
    }
```

Would it work if I just add `#pragma omp parallel for` at the top? Or are there other (better) ways?

Comment: Yes, `#pragma omp parallel for` for external loop is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `#pragma omp parallel for` for your external loop is fine, you should get your intended results using the code below:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, sum) shared(y, n, m, A, x)
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    int sum=0;
    for(j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
        sum += A[i][j]*x[j];
    }
    y[i]=sum
}
```

Note that in order to get any form of noticeable improvement your `n` variable is going to have to be very large. Small `n` values will actually degrade your performance substantially due to thread overhead and a phenomenon called [False Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

<s>As an end note, *If* your final intention is to sum up `y` - you can make use of the OpenMP [reduction](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION) clause.</s>

Comment: I doubt his final intention is to sum up `y` since this obviously is a dense matrix-vector multiplication code. MVM is known to be memory- rather than compute-bound. Any combination of `n * m` that leads to `A[][]` being larger than the last-level cache would result in poor to no parallel speed-up at all.